# ap-linux in a vm, does this make sense?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, audio, virtual-machine, virtualization

[AudioPhile Linux](http://www.ap-linux.com/), a distro tailor made to play audio has interested me. However I don't consider it desktop-grade and I don't have a spare machine to use it with.

Does it make sense to run audio-tailored software it in a VM (VirtualBox)?

Specifically will the audio output of a vm be capable of being better than the host OS, or will the audio be "filtered", passed though pulseaudio on its way to the real hardware?